# Making a C callable write/print function in x64 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to make a write function in x64 that I can call in a C file.

I have the following files

write.s

```
.text
.globl write

write:
    // stack thing
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    
    // function arguments as done by the C convention
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp) // fd
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp) // buf
    movl    %edx, -12(%rbp) // length
    
    // write
    movq    $1, %rax // syscall 1 for write
    movq    -4(%rbp), %rdi // fd to rdi
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rsi // buf to rsi
    movq    -12(%rbp), %rdx // len to rdx
    syscall
    
    // return
    movq    %rbp, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

write.h

```
void write(int fd, char *buf, int len);
```

main.c

```
#include "write.h"

int main() {
    int fd = 1;
    char *buf = "hi";
    int len = 2;
    write(fd, buf, len);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I compile this with `gcc -no-pie -o main write.s main.c`
and run `./main` it doesn't output anything.
I'm sorry if this is some obvious mistake, as I am not that familiar with x64 assembly.

Comment: On x86_64 the system call number for write is actually 64... You should include <asm/unistd.h> in your .s file.

Comment: @AhmedMasud Isn't it 1? 64 is semget https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/constants/syscalls.md#x86_64-64_bit

Comment: You used 32 bits to save the arguments. That won't work. Also it's totally pointless to go through memory especially since they are already in the proper place. And you don't need a stack frame either. The whole function can literally be 3 instructions: `movl $1, %eax; syscall; ret`.

Comment: @Jester that worked. Thank you. I originally had only those 3 instructions along with the stack frame, because I've had problems with the compiler when I don't include it, but it didn't work. Here it seems to work even without it though, so it must have been something to do with the stack frame.